# Unknown error when running robolectric

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am new to robolectric and all I want is to run simple test.

I use Android Studio => Gradle

When I run my sample test

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final int expected = 5;
    final int reality = 5;
    assertEquals(expected, reality);
}
}
```

using gradle

```
 ./gradlew clean test --stacktrace
```

I got exception

```
    test.ExampleTest > test FAILED
        java.lang.RuntimeException
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    1 test completed, 1 failed
    :app:testDebug FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
    > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/gburanov/code/mobile/Medoo.Android/app/build/test-report/debug/index.html

    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Exception is:

    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
```

How to find the real source of error? Nullpoint exception where?

Answer (score 1):

For Robolectric you shouldn't extend InstrumentationTestCase.

Comment: what should I extend then?

Comment: You don't have to extend anything.

Answer (score 0):

that should be your path to more failure details:

```
file:///Users/gburanov/code/mobile/Medoo.Android/app/build/test-report/debug/index.html
```